# OkHttp SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted on android 4

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, handshake

Hello our API migrate to TLS 1.2. I apply solution that was proposed here https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372 and it works fine on test API.
https://api.fastly.com/public-ip-list
https://tlstest.paypal.com/
However it doesn't work on my API. I found out that my API use the same clipper as tested url TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.
So as I understand it should work, but it's not. Does anyone know what can be the reason of this problem?
Error log:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb950bc70: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x9c8367f1:0x00000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- downgrade your dependencies to use `OkHttp` version before 3.10.0
- downgrade security on backend side to support old cipher suites
- stop to support Android OS < 5
- try to fix with solutions posted here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4053